# Flex selecteditem get next item

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

So i am using a list taken from an xml to load in mp3 files, you can start an mp3 file by clicking on it. Then i get the item clicked on like this:

```
var mp3Url:String = trackListList.selectedItem.@url;
```

I am pretty new to flex and i wondered if there was a way to select the next item based on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way would be like this:

```
var selIndex:int=trackList.dataProvider.getItemIndex(trackListList.selectedItem);
if(selIndex != -1) {
    selIndex++;
    nextMP3:String=trackList.dataProvider.getItemAt(selIndex).@url;
}
```

**EDIT**

```
var selIndex:int=trackList.selectedIndex;
if(selIndex != -1) {
    selIndex++;
    nextMP3:String=trackList.dataProvider.getItemAt(selIndex).@url;
}
```

`selIndex` is the index of the item selected in the data provider. -1 means nothing is selected

Comment: is the if(selIndex != -1) detection if an index is selected?

Comment: Actually, that code is not necessary at all. 1 sec, lemme edit